# What is the difference between the three ways of loading typescript module dependencies?

Tags: requirejs, typescript, amd, js-amd, typescript1.4

What is the difference between the following ways of loading typescript module dependencies?

```
/// <amd-dependency path="someFile"/>

/// <reference path="someFile.ts" />

import someFile = require("someFile");
```

Comment: Have you read this? https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript

Comment: But what about <amd-dependency path=" ">?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Covered here : https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript

Disclaimer : **My strong opinions follow** : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

> import someFile = require("someFile");

This should be your main form of import. Use this for JS libraries `import $ = require("jquery");` as well as its relative file variant for your own files
`import someFile = require("./someFile");`

> /// reference path="someFile.ts" /

use this only to import *type* information from `.d.ts` files and your very own `globals.d.ts` or `vendors.d.ts` or `tsd.d.ts`

> amd-dependency path="someFile"

You don't need this *unless* you want to `require` stuff in *CSS* / *images* **into** your TS.

Comment: `import $ = require("jquery");` using AMD?

Comment: @Tarh Yes. Please see https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

Comment: I read your document. A question: `/// <reference` is still useful in describing an external module, isn't it?

Comment: Nope. `/// <reference` is not needed anymore. `tsconfig.json` is going to be the new *compilation context*.

Comment: Thank you, `tsconfig.json` is amazing!

Comment: @basarat And what about the ES6 style imports? Are they just the same as `import foo = require("bar")` ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to figure out why there's no mention of this style/example: `import {Injectable} from "@angular/core"`? Is this not for modules, only for classes or are they the same thing?

Comment: @basarat `tsconfig.json is going to be the new compilation context.` is this explained somewhere in the official TS handbook?